# Error 999999 when converting a point feature class to a raster in python

Tags: arcpy, raster, error-999999

After having converted my xyz-file to a point feature class, I am trying to convert to a grid using a Python snippet. The data represents river bathymetry. However, when executing the script, I get: *'ERROR 999999: Error executing function'*.

There must be something wrong with my input data, or with the arguments in the python snippet. I already changed double quotes into singles (worked for me with a previous problem), and before converting my .pts-input file to a point feature class, I checked for any odd lines that might contain string - in this file there are none.

This is my code (the converting-to-point-feature-class section does work):

The variable *fn* is simply the input file name defined earlier on in the script. *RDnew* is a coordinate system that was also defined earlier on in the script.

```
    print 'Converting to point feature class.'
    pts_shp = fn[0:8] + '.shp'  #output file name (using fn[0:8] to get rid of the .pts or .txt extension)
    arcpy.ASCII3DToFeatureClass_3d(fn,'XYZ','.\\shp_points\\' + pts_shp,'POINT','1',RDnew,'#','#','DECIMAL_POINT')

    print 'Converting to grid.'
    output_grid = 'grid_' + fn[3:8]
    arcpy.PointToRaster_conversion('.\\shp_points\\' + pts_shp,'Shape.Z','.\\grids\\' + output_grid,'MOST_FREQUENT','NONE','1')
```

Error 999999 does not really get me anywhere. Do you have any suggestions on what might be wrong with my input / code?

Comment: i don't often utilize that tool, but could it be that 'MOST_FREQUENT' is used in conjunction with a 'NONE' field? - or a cell size of 1 could be ridiculously large depending on the extent and map units?

Comment: That shouldn't be the problem; this is the default. I used it on a different (smaller) dataset, that worked fine. The cell size should be fine too: 1x1m in a ~ 250x350 km map extent.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you have advanced license and the necessary extension 3D  analyst? I am not sure if you need it for the ASCII3DToFeatureClass_3d function but you might for the feature to raster conversion. Did you check out the 3D analysis extensions early on in your script?
   Here is an example code from [ESRI](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/3d_analyst_tools/ascii_3d_to_feature_class_3d_analyst_.htm) to import arcgisscripting 
   (for the ASCII to feature class part) and you can check in 3D using

   `/* Check out the 3D license.
   arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")
   /* your code here
   /* Check the license in when you finish
   arcpy.CheckInExtension("3D")`
2. Another issue is you have a field name **'Shape.Z'** specified in your point to raster conversion line, I am not sure if dots are allowed within an attribute column name. Try changing it into 'Shape_Z' in the corresponding column name of the resulting shapefile from your ASCII to Shape conversion.

*I don't have enough reps to comment under your post that is why I've put this as an answer.

Comment: i think the XYZ refers to the [input file type](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00q900000041000000).

Comment: you are correct I missed the file type argument between input file and output file name. thanks. I edited my answer